# How do I use the rails console on a remote production server via capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, production

I want to manually create a user with my rails console on my remote server with Capistrano.

However, if I ssh into the server and simply type `rails c` it says `Command 'rails' not found`.

Does anyone have a method to access the production rails console through Capistrano?

Comment: navigate to your project's `current` directory and do `bundle exec rails c`

Comment: That seems like a bit of over kill if you know the production database specifics.If so then you can just run `rails c -e production` locally to connect to the production db. If your database.yml file has environment variables for things like host and password they can be prefaced to the commands as such `DB_PASS="some password" DB_HOST="MY HOST" rails c -e production`

Comment: @engineersmnky that's assuming database is accessible from the internet. Which shouldn't be the case in pretty much all cases where DB is self-hosted (and doesn't come from a DBaaS)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev very true it does make some assumptions as to open ports on the DB server however it does not imply an internet accessible database server. I have self hosted databases that are accessible via intranet but not internet in which this functionality would still work